# Can an analytic function defined on a maximal torus be extended analytically to all the Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, analyticity, analytic-continuation

Let $G$ be a compact group and $T$ a maximal torus on $G$. Suppose $f$ is an analytic function defined on $T$. Is there an analytic function $F$ on $G$ whose restriction agrees with $f$ on $T$?